# unserialize error in sparkR

Tags: r, serialization, parallel-processing, sparkr

I am very new to SparkR (and parallelization in general). I am running SparkR locally (I know that is not the right usage of spark but I am just getting started) and I have tried to re-write some part of my code with sparkR though 
collect gives me the following errors by increasing the number of samples as (no error for small number of samples):

```
Error in unserialize(obj) : 
ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R
Calls: assetForecast ... convertJListToRList -> lapply -> lapply -> FUN   -> unserialize
Execution halted
```

and the other error which is is probably because of my low memory is:

```
heap memory error (trying increasing JVM memory & driver memory did not help)
```

I would appreciate any help regarding FIRST error (I posted the second error since I thought they may be somehow related even though I get them by setting different values for numSlices in parallelize). I think the first one may be a version incompatibility between spark, sparkR and R that causes this serialization issue. I tried installing different version though pretty soon stuck with resolving dependency.

Here is a sample script which simulates what I am doing in SparkR (the error are generated for input.len > 950):

```
library(SparkR) # load sparkR library
sc <- sparkR.init() ## initialize the sparkR
input.len <- 8000 # size of the input
num.slice <- 2 # number of slices for parallelize function

## Define a few functions to simulate actual calculations
latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2015/12/31") {
   ## create random date of length N
   st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
   et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
   dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
   ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
   rt <- st + ev
}

encode <- function(ele1, ele2) {
   ## concatenate ele1 and ele2, seperated by %
   return (paste(toString(ele1), toString(ele2), sep = "%"))
}

decode <- function(coded) {
   ## separate input string by %
   idx <- regexpr("%", coded)[1]
   ele1 <- as.numeric(substr(coded, 1, idx-1))
   ele2 <- substr(coded, idx + 1, nchar(coded))
   return (list(ele1, ele2))
 }

 fakeFun <- function(asset.age, asset.year) {
    ## fake function to simulate my actual function
    return (as.list(rep(asset.age, 10)))
 }

  wrapperFun <- function(x) {
     asset.age <- decode(x)[[1]]
     asset.y <- decode(x)[[1]]
     df <- fakeFun(asset.age, asset.y)
     return (df)
  }

  ## Start of calculations with SparkR
  calc.ts <- latemail(input.len) ## create fake years
  asset.ages <- runif(input.len) * 10 ## create fake ages

  paired <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(asset.ages)) {
     ## keep information of both years and ages in one vector
     ## using encode function
     paired[[length(paired) + 1]] <- encode(asset.ages[[i]], calc.ts[[i]])
  }

  rdd.paired <- parallelize(sc, paired, numSlices = num.slice)
  rdd.df <- lapply(rdd.paired, wrapperFun)
  rdd.list <- collect(rdd.df)
  print(rdd.list)
  sparkR.stop()
```

Here is the full report of error:

```
for numSlice = 5 in parallelize function:
    > rdd.list <- collect(rdd.df)
    15/07/22 17:20:40 INFO RRDD: Times: boot = 0.434 s, init = 0.015 s, broadcast = 0.000 s, read-input = 0.003 s, compute = 0.200 s, write-output = 0.004 s, total = 0.656 s
    15/07/22 17:20:41 INFO RRDD: Times: boot = 0.010 s, init = 0.017 s, broadcast = 0.000 s, read-input = 0.003 s, compute = 0.193 s, write-output = 0.004 s, total = 0.227 s
    15/07/22 17:20:41 INFO RRDD: Times: boot = 0.010 s, init = 0.013 s, broadcast = 0.001 s, read-input = 0.002 s, compute = 0.191 s, write-output = 0.003 s, total = 0.220 s
    15/07/22 17:20:41 INFO RRDD: Times: boot = 0.010 s, init = 0.011 s, broadcast = 0.000 s, read-input = 0.002 s, compute = 0.191 s, write-output = 0.004 s, total = 0.218 s
    15/07/22 17:20:41 INFO RRDD: Times: boot = 0.014 s, init = 0.015 s, broadcast = 0.000 s, read-input = 0.003 s, compute = 0.213 s, write-output = 0.004 s, total = 0.249 s
    Error in unserialize(obj) : 
      ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R
    Calls: collect ... convertJListToRList -> lapply -> lapply -> FUN -> unserialize
    Execution halted

for numSlice = 6 in parallelize function
15/07/22 17:18:52 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.readData(RRDD.scala:258)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.readData(RRDD.scala:243)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD.read(RRDD.scala:200)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD$$anon$1.next(RRDD.scala:70)
        scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD$$anon$1.foreach(RRDD.scala:66)
        scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD$$anon$1.to(RRDD.scala:66)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD$$anon$1.toBuffer(RRDD.scala:66)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD$$anon$1.toArray(RRDD.scala:66)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/07/22 17:18:52 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Error in readTypedObject(con, type) : 
  Unsupported type for deserialization 
Calls: collect ... callJMethod -> invokeJava -> readObject -> readTypedObject
Execution halted
```

Is there really a problem in my SparkR installation? If yes, how it runs for small number of samples?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of SparkR are you using? I got the error could not find function parallelize when I run with SparkR 1.4.0.
Furthermore it seems that you're collecting an RDD, while in SparkR 1.4.0 collect is only available for DataFrames, which could cause the error (if this is the case, create an sqlContext and convert your RDD with the function createDataFrame).

Comment: I downloaded it from here (https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg) and I believe its version 1.2 (https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/rdocs/1.2/)

Comment: As of Spark-1.4.0 SparkR is integrated in Spark, you can download it on http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html You should rewrite your code however, since for the moment parallelize is not available nor collect on an RDD, but you can put it in a SparkR DataFrame and do your calculations there.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is how it works (or should work in Spark-1.4.0). First initialize a sqlContext as well:

```
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

And than change your code starting from

```
paired <- list()
```

in

```
# Create a vector instead of a list
paired <- c()
for (i in 1:length(asset.ages)) {
  ## keep information of both years and ages in one vector
  ## using encode function
  paired[length(paired) + 1] <- encode(asset.ages[[i]], calc.ts[[i]])
}

# What you actually need is a data.frame or SparkR DataFrame
paired.data.frame <- data.frame(paired=paired)
paired.DataFrame  <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, paired.data.frame)
# Map function returns an RDD which you can not collect yet
# Therefor convert it to a DataFrame again
paired.df         <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, map(paired.DataFrame,wrapperFun))
# This DataFrame you can collect
paired.result     <- collect(paired.df)
```

Why did I say should work in my first sentence? It works when I run it on my laptop, but I altered the SparkR source code to make map available.
I do not know however to fix this in SparkR 1.2, but would suggest anyway to change to Spark-1.4.0 since SparkR is integrated in Spark since then.

Comment: Thanks. However, altering the source code (map function) is not an option for me and I am looking for a solution that  can use sparkR as black box. Is there any way that we can do this without modifying the source code? Thanks,

Comment: I guess that in SparkR-1.4.0 there is no other way yet, if you want, I can provide you with the altered source code.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can send me the altered source code (you can also put it on github so I can fork from you). I want to know how to work with these dataframes.

Comment: I've added the code to github on https://github.com/wannesrosiers/SparkR/tree/master. You should first download Spark-1.4.0 from https://spark.apache.org and then overwrite Spark-1.4.0/R/pkg with my code. Only a few adaptations are made, one of them is making the map-function public.